# MATLAB: polyval function graphs multiple lines for N>1

Tags: matlab

I am trying to graph a polynomial function using the following code:

```
y = polyfit(P,C,3);
Line = polyval(y, P);

y =

2.0372e-14  -4.0614e-09 0.0002  2.6060

figure
plot(P,C,'.')
hold on
plot(P, Line, '-')
legend('Observations','y')
axis([0 90000 0 10])
```

The problem is, it produces multiple lines like this:

[image]

This problem does not occur if I set N = 1 or `y = polyfit(P,C,1);`. In that case I get a proper graph with one line:

[image]

How can I graph just 1 line for N = 3?

Here is an Excel version of what I am trying to produce in Matlab:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your observations `P` are in an arbitrary order: Matlab is going from point to point in that order. You don't actually need to plot the fitted curve at each value `P`, you just need to plot the fitted curve over the range of `P`:

```
Pfitted = linspace(min(P),max(P),1000) % Generate 1000 equally spaced points
Cfitted = polyval(y,Pfitted) % Fit to these points
plot(Pfitted,Cfitted,'-')
```

Comment: PS, your choice of variable names is confusing!

Comment: Thank you! I apologize for mixing up variables. I used `y` as the predicted value. The second line in your code should be `Cfitted = polyval(y,Pfitted)`. Sorry about mixing `p` and `y` again

Comment: Change made - I admit, I hadn't tested it!